# Remove IntelliCode icon

Tags: visual-studio

VS2022.

There's an "intellicode completions" icon at the bottom left of the editor. When I click it, it gives me completion settings. I confuse it with a bookmark. How do I remove it?

https://alextumanoff.medium.com/visual-studio-2022-intellicode-completions-52f25c6ffd97

Why do I need an icon for it, anyway? Do they expect me to change this setting on a regular basis?

[image: icon]

Comment: Use Help > Send Feedback to tell them what you think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall IntelliCode.

Use Resharper C++ instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option currently available to remove this icon (As of VS 2022 17.5). I have submitted feedback to the Visual Studio team so feel free to upvote for their visibility:

[No option exists to remove the Intellicode completions/suggestions icon](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/No-option-exists-to-remove-the-Intellico/10291149?port=1026&fsid=23d31a3f-b1e8-446a-b3ca-1e7d97d53e35)